# No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to run this [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info/example) in the plugin page
and i get this error

```
I/flutter ( 3273): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)
I/flutter ( 3273): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:153:7)
I/flutter ( 3273): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 3273): #1      DeviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo (package:device_info/device_info.dart:25:35)
I/flutter ( 3273): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 3273): #2      _MyAppState.initPlatformState (/data/user/0/com.yourcompany.demos/cache/demosSWKRJL/demos/lib/main.dart:37:67)
I/flutter ( 3273): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 3273): #3      _MyAppState.initState (/data/user/0/com.yourcompany.demos/cache/demosSWKRJL/demos/lib/main.dart:29:5)
I/flutter ( 3273): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3734:58)
I/flutter ( 3273): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
I/flutter ( 3273): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
I/flutter ( 3273): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
I/flutter ( 3273): #8      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:852:16)
I/flutter ( 3273): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:823:5)
I/flutter ( 3273): #10     RenderObje
```

Comment: have you included  `device_info: "^0.2.0"` in `pubspec.yaml`
better share your code so that it is easy to understand the problem
as your shared example code is perfectly working

Comment: Please run `flutter doctor -v`  and paste the result - I've just run the plugin with no problem on my system. Also, try running `flutter packages get` before running the app. You might also want to try upgrading to the most recent flutter using `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: i think it was a bug because a tried the example is a real phone and it works and tried  again and it works very well , thnks

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 48):

this isn't a bug

and it isn't about platform specific coding as @challenget answered

- you just need to re-build and run the app again for flutter-plugin to be added and work correctly.

*hot-restart won't work*

:hearts [this is a feature-request btw]

Comment: This is the valid answer.

Comment: This was my case

Comment: In my case that was a solution. I had to turn it off and on again.

Comment: I KNEW it was related to that!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 20):

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
}
```

You need to judge the device.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

follow this 4 steps it will work

```
  flutter clean
```

---

```
flutter pub get
```

---

```
flutter clean
```

---

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the app and restart the build. This worked for me.

Comment: Isn't it already what [Leo Ma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010310/2227743) is saying?

Answer (score 0):

follow these 4 steps it will work

**flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter clean
flutter run**

or
Stop the app and restart the build. This worked for me.