# device information in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, device

I am trying to get unique id of both android and ios using `device_info: ^2.0.3` package. As long as I use that package I need to rebuild the apps to get device information, hot reload will not work. I get that solution from this [No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027351/no-implementation-found-for-method-getandroiddeviceinfo).
Right now, I have an apps that being uploaded in playstore (let's say that it is 1.0.0 version) and I would like to update the apps (into 1.1.0 version) by giving user information about their device by using `device_package`. As I was explained before.. that I need to rebuild the apps to use `device_package`.
So my question is... should user uninstall the apps that has been downloaded from playstore and then re-install again to get device information in newest version (1.1.0) ? or by doing `update` apps from playstore is enough ?

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild or hot-reload has nothing to do with your user reinstall or update. For any changes to be deployed to the users, you MUST rebuild the APK/AAB file and upload it to playstore. The user can simply update if they already installed it, or they can reinstall if they want.

Comment: Hi, so sorry for late reply but thanks a lot for the explanation and information you have given to me. That helps me to make sure the deployment process